# Theano Installation On windows 64

Tags: theano

Im new in Python and Theano library. I want to install Theano on windows 7-64. I have a display adapters :
Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 which is not compatible with NVIDA.

My QUESTIONS:

1-Is obligatory to install CUDA to i can use Theano?
2- Even if i have an Ubuntu opearting system, with the same display adapters, CUDA still mandatory?

Any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need CUDA to run Theano.

Theano can run on either CPU or GPU. If you want to run on GPU you must (currently) use CUDA which means you must be using a NVIDIA display adapter. Without CUDA/NVIDIA you must run on CPU.

There is no disadvantage to running on CPU other than speed -- Theano can be much faster on GPU but everything that runs on a GPU will also run on a CPU as long as it has been coded generically (the default and standard method for Theano code).